# Setting timeout for cron jobs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, timeout

Do Ubuntu Linux cron (Vixie cron?) support setting timeout for its jobs?

Specifically, the process would be killed after X seconds unless it finishes successfully by then.

I have had some cases where tasks have been hanging due to network connectivity and various issues. The process are left to hanging forever unless you manually clean up and kill them.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

On Ubuntu the command [timeout](http://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) exists, which is part of coreutils.  You can use it like this to set a timeout.  Older versions of Debian/Ubuntu didn't build and include this command, but there is a comparable `timeout` package that you can install.

```
# puppet shouldn't take more then 40 minutes!
47 * * * * root /usr/bin/timeout 2400 /usr/bin/puppet agent ...
```

Comment: The duration can also have a suffix ("s" for seconds, "m" for minutes, "h" for hours and "d" for days). So for better readability, the above could also be written as 47 * * * * root /usr/bin/timeout 40m /usr/bin/puppet agent ...

Comment: No it can't.  at least not with the implementation I had when writing this question.   The new version in coreutils has the s suffix.  The version I had on older Debian systems didn't.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think this is possible. You'll have to build the check into your application.